# ffmpeg copy video in video with a specific time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Im new in this topic (beginner) and Im german... So it's a bit difficult to find the correct words...

I'll try to explain what I've done and what I want to do:

1. Extract video area from the original video converted in PRORES codec:

   > ffmpeg.exe -i test.mkv -ss 00:06:21.99 -t 00:00:01.94 -async 1 -strict -2 -c:v prores_ks -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -profile:v 4444 -bits_per_mb 8000 -s 1920x1080 cut_video.mov
2. Edit the cut in After Effects
3. Convert the PRORES in Matroska

   > ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\ffmpeg-20170202-08b0981-win64-static\bin\cut_video\cut_video.mov" -vcodec ffv1 -acodec pcm_s16le temp.mkv
4. Replace the video area in the originale video file at the time 00:06:21.99...

I spend 4 hours for the two commands... 
So I despair at the fourth step. Is it possible? Can you help me?

I made a picture, so you can understand better what Im doing...: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBubC.jpg

Best regards from germany,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can skip step 3 and just merge the edited file with the original.

You can do this either using a combination of the trim and concat filters, or using the overlay filter. I'll show the use of the overlay here.

```
ffmpeg -i full.mkv -i AE-edit.mov -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+381.99/TB[ae];[0][ae]overlay=enable='gte(t,381.99)':shortest=1[v]" -c:a copy -map "[v]" -map 0:a out.mkv
```

`381.99` is the start-time of the trim in seconds. Make sure the  edited file has the same resolution and frame rate as the full file, else more filters will be needed, which will complicate things. Verify the start time is accurate. Currently, it doesn't look accurate as unless you are dealing with a 100+ fps video, `.99` ending doesn't mark the presentation time of a video frame. (a 25 fps video will have frames starting at .00, .04, .08..etc)

Comment: Thank you very much! :) My problem is now, that ffmpeg uses 100% of my memory (32GB). That freezes my pc. Both videos have a framerate of 23.976216 (23.976)

Comment: How long is your video?

Comment: The duration is about 23 Minuten (23:42), with a file size of 1,98 GB.